# Как добавить путь в REST API на QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, rest

написал простенький класс который работает как однопоточный http сервер, выдающий текущее время и дату, если обратиться по 127.0.0.1 :

**simple_server.h**

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_SERVER_H
#define SIMPLE_SERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDateTime>

class Simple_Server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Simple_Server(QObject *parent = 0);
    void incomingConnection(qintptr handle);

signals:

public slots:
    void onReadyRead();
    void onDisconnected();

};

#endif // SIMPLE_SERVER_H
```

**simple_server.cpp**

```
#include "simple_server.h"

Simple_Server::Simple_Server(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    if(listen(QHostAddress::Any, 80))
    {
        qDebug() << "listerning...";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "error " << errorString();
    }
}

void Simple_Server::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    connect(socket,
            SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this,
            SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    connect(socket,
            SIGNAL(disconnected()),
            this,
            SLOT(onDisconnected()));
}

void Simple_Server::onReadyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket * socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    qDebug() << socket->readAll();

    QString response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n%1";
    socket->write(response.arg(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString()).toUtf8());
    socket->disconnectFromHost();
}

void Simple_Server::onDisconnected()
{
    QTcpSocket * socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());    
    socket->close();
    socket->deleteLater();
}
```

Вопрос в том как добавить разные директории(наверное это так называется)
Например чтобы по обращению к **127.0.0.1/time** сервер выдавал время, в по запросу **127.0.0.1/date** сервер выдавал дату. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Нужно резализовать подмножество протокола HTTP, которое будет хотя бы парсить из GET-запроса путь.

Comment: Можно по подробнее, не совсем понял в чем суть

Comment: Сейчас вы дампите все заголовки и тело запроса в `qDebug()`, а для описанной задачи вам придётся всё-таки разбирать по кусочкам, что там написано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам в этой строке

```
qDebug() << socket->readAll();
```

уже приходят данные. Достаточно сохрантить их в строку, потом применить метод split('\n') и разбить на строки. Первая строка будет содержать три элемента, которые можно тем же split разбить.

обычный вид

```
GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
```

первое  - это метод. Тут вариантов не много. Обычно это GET/POST/PUT/DELETE, но можно и свое вставить. Оно соответствует тому, как запросили. Дальше идет то, что вы назвали "разные директории". Собственно оно и нужно. И самый конец - это версия HTTP, но Вам скорее всего пока можно просто игнорировать.

То есть, где то так

```
QStringList h = QString(socket->readAll()).split('\n');
QStringList f = h.split(' ');
QString method = f[0];
QString path = f[1];

// дальше решаем.
QString response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n%1";
if (path == '/date") {
  socket->write(response.arg(QDateTime::currentDate().toString()).toUtf8());
} else if (path == "/time") {
    socket->write(response.arg(QDateTime::currentTime().toString()).toUtf8());
} else {

    socket->write(response.arg("error");
}
socket->disconnectFromHost();
```

Конечно, эта реализация очень простая и в ней есть много-много недостатков. Но она должна работать.

Comment: ошибка в QStringList f = h.split(' '); поправил на QStringList f = h.at(0).split(' ');

Comment: там просто опечатка. `QStringList f = h[0].split(' ');`